# How to loop through a list to count keys from dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to run through a speech that is parsed into a list called speech and count each instance of the punctuation mark and +1 the value in the dictionary. I have a punctuation list and dictionary below.

```py
punclist = ['.', '!', '?']
puncdict = {'.':0,'!':0,'?':0}
```

Comment: Try iterating through the list with a `for` loop (`for {some_punctuation_mark} in punclist`) and incrementing the respective dictionary value `puncdict[{some_punctuation_mark}] += 1` on each iteration.

Comment: Please read [ask]. It's not clear what you are trying to do, and anyway you are expected to make *some* attempt at doing it yourself. At the very least, you should be able to show an example of what the input to the code might look like, and what the corresponding output should be, and explain the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the speech is a list, but you could use a `collection.Counter()` to count occurrences of each character, then pick out those of interest:

```
from collections import Counter

text = 'We will fight them on the beaches! Where are the apples? Oh, they are over there. etc. etc. etc.'

c = Counter(text)
punclist = ['.', '!', '?']
punctuation_counts = {k: c[k] for k in punclist}
print(punctuation_counts)
# {'.': 4, '!': 1, '?': 1}
```

If you have a list of words then you would do this:

```
c = Counter(''.join(word_list))
```

And if you want counts for all punctuation characters:

```
import string

punctuation_counts = {k: c[k] for k in string.punctuation}
print(punctuation_counts)
# {'!': 1, '"': 0, '#': 0, '$': 0, '%': 0, '&': 0, "'": 0, '(': 0, ')': 0, '*': 0, '+': 0, ',': 1, '-': 0, '.': 4, '/': 0, ':': 0, ';': 0, '<': 0, '=': 0, '>': 0, '?': 1, '@': 0, '[': 0, '\\': 0, ']': 0, '^': 0, '_': 0, '`': 0, '{': 0, '|': 0, '}': 0, '~': 0}
```